# How can I reference a date inside of a cell in Google Script Editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script that pulls events from Google Calendar to Google sheets for a singular date. I want the user to be able to type the date on the spreadsheet (in this case, in the cell F1), and then when you run the script, the script gets all the events for the relevant date. However, with my current code, I can only type in the date in the script editor, as the script won't run when I try to reference F1 in lieu of the written-out date. What am I doing wrong?

```
function getEvents() {

    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("email@email.com");
    var events = cal.getEventsForDay(new Date("2/5/2020"));

    for(var i = 0;i<events.length;i++){
    var title = events[i].getTitle();
    Logger.log(title);
    ss.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(title);
 }    
}
```

In short, I'd love to reference a cell in line 5, rather than the string of the date.
Sorry if this is so simple, I've never coded before so this is all new to me! Thank you for any help!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? In the upper of the script, you say `I try to reference F1`. But in below of the script, `I'd love to reference a cell in line 5`. I cannot understand about your goal. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: Sure. I want to reference cell F1 instead of the date in Line 5.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to retrieve the titles of events retrieving with `getEventsForDay(Date)`.
- You want to retrieve `Date` of `getEventsForDay(Date)` from the cell "F1" on the active sheet in the Spreadsheet.
- You want to put the titles to the column "A" of row 2 on the active sheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("email@email.com");
var events = cal.getEventsForDay(new Date("2/5/2020"));
```

To:

```
var inputtedValue = ss.getRange("F1").getValue();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("email@email.com");
var events = cal.getEventsForDay(inputtedValue);
```

- When the value of the cell is the Date object, `getValue()` can be retrieved the value as the Date object.

  - If the value of cell "F1" is not the Date object, an error might occur. In that case, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### References:

- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)